# Label ID detection upon click with for tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have labels with for="#input_id" tag as illustrated below. However, multiple labels trigger the same input field (with id) to attach a user selected file. I want to now which label triggered the input field.

```
<label id="label1" for="input1">Document1</label>
<label id="label2" for="input1">Document2</label>
<label id="label3" for="input1">Document3</label>
<label id="label4" for="input1">Document4</label>

<input type="file" id="input1" accept="application/pdf" />

$("#input1").change(function() {
//some js for checking file type and file size etc
//looking for some code to findout which label clicked to trigger file input 

});
```

When i click labels it triggers input field however i need to know which label clicked to save file path to suitable div by using data-fpath="some path".

I use jquery however any javascript solution is OK for me.

Comment: your question is not clear to me

Comment: You should search on web first to ask this question. Clearly you did not'

Comment: `$('label').on('click', function(e) { console.log(e.target.id) });`

Comment: I am looking for which label triggered the input field, i am not looking for which label clicked. 

With your perspective, after label click event, i have to trigger input field. That is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below working snippet :

```js
$("label").on('click',function(){
  $("label").removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
$("#input1").change(function() {
  //some js for checking file type and file size etc
  //looking for some code to findout which label clicked to trigger file input 
  if($(".clicked").length>0){
    alert('Label with id : '+$(".clicked").attr('id')+' clicked to trigger file uploader.');
  }else{
    alert("No label has been clicked trigger file uploader.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="label1" for="input1">Document1</label>
<label id="label2" for="input1">Document2</label>
<label id="label3" for="input1">Document3</label>
<label id="label4" for="input1">Document4</label>

<input type="file" id="input1" accept="application/pdf" />
```

Comment: Hi Rahul,  your answer is a working one. However still first we need to catch click event of label and then catch change event of input field. I asked if someone know how the label's for event pass its own parameters (if so) to click event of input field.  Thanks for your kind answer

Comment: @aliaktas where exact you want which label has been clicked to trigger file uploader field?

Comment: Yes, below explanation might be more clear:

When you click a label with a **for** tag, it automatically fires an event for target object. However, i ask if that label with for tag, passes its parameters (id, class, etc) to triggered object ( in that case it is an input field)